# How to create matrices with the Linear library in Haskell

Tags: haskell, linear-algebra

The [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.5.0/docs/Data-Matrix.html) for Linear shows how you can create vectors and matrices using the V1,V2,V3,V4 functions to create vectors of dimensions 1,2,3,4. But I would like to work with matrices that have more elements.

The matrix multiplication [example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.7/docs/Linear-Matrix.html) shows and example using a function `fromList`.

```
V2 (fromList [(1,2)]) (fromList [(2,3)]) !*! fromList [(1,V3 0 0 1), (2, V3 0 0 5)]
```

But I can't seem to find that function in the Linear library. How would I go about creating a matrix of double values with arbitrary dimensions (e.g. 5x6)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `(!*!)`'s type

```
(!*!) :: (Functor m, Foldable t, Additive t, Additive n, Num a)
      => m (t a) -> t (n a) -> m (n a)
```

The important constraint here is `Additive`, so look at its instances

```
instance Additive []
instance Additive Vector -- ordinary, unsized vectors from the vectors package
instance Additive V0
instance Additive V1
instance Additive V2
instance Additive V3
instance Additive V4 -- Sized vectors from linear up to n = 4
instance Dim n => Additive (V n) -- Vectors of arbitrary dimension where the size is given by a type level number n
-- plus other instances
```

So you can just use nested lists:

```
m :: [[Int]]
m = [ [ 0,1,2,3,4 ],
      [ 1,2,3,4,0 ],
      [ 2,3,4,0,1 ],
      [ 3,4,0,1,2 ],
      [ 4,0,1,2,3 ] ]

msq :: [[Int]]
msq = m !*! m
```

Or nested `Vectors`

```
import Data.Vector(Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector as V

mv :: Vector (Vector Int)
mv = V.fromList $ V.fromList <$> m

mvsq :: Vector (Vector Int)
mvsq = mv !*! mv
```

Or mix and match:

```
mvl :: Vector [Int]
mvl = V.fromList m
mlv :: [Vector Int]
mlv = V.fromList <$> m

mvlmlv :: Vector (Vector Int)
mvlmlv = mvl !*! mlv
```

And you can use `V` to keep track of the sizes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
import Linear.V

mV :: V 5 (V 5 Int) -- GHC.TypeLits.Nat literals
mV = fromJust $ fromVector $ fromJust <$> fromVector <$> mv
mVsq :: V 5 (V 5 Int)
mVsq = mV !*! mV -- does not compile in case of dimension mismatch
```